# Как импортировать иконку svg из zeplin в android studio корректно?

Tags: android-studio, svg

Есть макеты хранящиеся на доске zeplin.
Выбирая ту или иную иконку с места, где хранится набор иконок выбираю import to svg в результате чего имею файл my_icon.svg.

В android studio выбираю new > Vector Asset и в диалоговом окне выбираю путь до иконки. Но итоговый результат отличается от ожидаемого. Прилагаю два скрина.
Возможно кто то сталкивался с подобным или же есть другой более корректный способ импорта иконок?

[image: Ожидаемый результат - zeplin app]

[image: Фактический результат - android studio]

Comment: VectorDrawable, в который конвертируется ваше изображение, "проще" SVG (имеет [не полную совместимость](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#svg)) и некоторые вещи просто пропускает.

Comment: @pavlofff придется со сложными иконками работать как с набором png изображений? То есть на данный момент других вариантов *совсем* нет?

Comment: Как вариант, есть сторонние библиотеки под андроид по работе с SVG , погуглите.

Comment: @pavlofff благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена, но не факт что корректно. Как оказалось вектор очень плохо дружит с градиентом и тенями, по сему при использовании иконок с ними придется использовать стандартные png

UPD: Рабочее решение - http://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/